# Two domains, single portal, how to keep Facebook likes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, cross-domain

We use two domains for an single site and planning transition from original to second domain only (i.e. www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com both point to the same site). However we are unable to display number our Facebook likes (15K) on new domain, it simply counts from beginning.

I have googled for a solution but given solutions do not work:

1. Most notably using og:metadata in page header (or might be that we just did it wrong way).
2. Using iframe and pull facebook box from original domain.

Is transferring likes from domain to domain even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not possible. Likes are related to the url, so all likes made to the domain1 can't be transfered to domain2. If anything like that was possible, people would be selling likes. And it doesn't make any sense at all, if I liked www.domain1.com and after a while from nowhere my like changed from that to www.selfieshotgirls.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this crop up in your Googling?
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18978/retrieve-facebook-like-count-after-changing-url-structure-for-entire-website

I guess it depends on how you've set up the move, but it sounds as though facebook can be convinced to respect 301 redirects.

Comment: I haven't stumbled upon that post, but it made it clear to me. Thanks!